# Mathematical reasoning problem: Find the number of days observed.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A weatherman studying weather observed the following:

1. It rained on 7 days morning or afternoon.
2. When it rained in the afternoon it was clear in the morning.
3. There were 5 clear afternoons
4. There were 6 clear mornings.

How many days did the weatherman observe?

Couldn't figure out the approach for a long time.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: which of the following are possible? CC, CR, RC, RR

Comment: I think you'd get a better response here if you showed some effort on the problem.  Here's a start:  let $C$ be the number of "all clear" days, $M$ the number of days it was clear in the morning but raining in the afternoon.  $A$ the number of days it rained in the morning, but was clear in the afternoon.  Can you compute $M+A$? $C+A$? $C+M$?

Comment: @lulu This approach was simply evading my wits . I apologise for being so unimaginative. Thanks to you I did figure out the solution to the problem. I am writing the answer myself; please review if you may.

Comment: Glad to have helped; I'll review your post when it appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael Burr and @lulu 's hints I could figure out the question myself:

- There are three possibilities: CC CR RC RR
- Mentioned that when it rained in the afternoon it was clear in the morning. Hence the RR case is not possible.

  ```
  CC+CR = 6
  CR+RC = 7
  RC+CC = 5
  ```

From the above equations

```
    CC = 2
    CR = 4
    RC = 3
```

So the total is 9.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the number of afternoons it rained, $M$ be the number of mornings it rained, and $D$ be the total number of days observed.  Facts 1 and 2 imply $A+M=7$.  Fact 3 implies $A=D-5$ and Fact 4 implies $M=D-6$.  Putting this together we have

$$7=A+M=2D-11$$

which implies $D=9$.

Answer (score -1):

Number 2 is equivalent to : When it rained in the morning it was clear in the afternoon ($A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $~B\Rightarrow ~A$).
This means that on no day it rained in the morning and in the afternoon.

There were 6 days clear mornings and 5 days clear afternoon. Some ($x$) of these days were clear morning and afternoon. So the weather man observed $s=11-x$ days of which $s-x=11-2x$ were only clear morning or only clear afternoon. But this is the number of days were it rained morning or afternoon. So it holds $s-x=11-2x=7$ which means $x=2$ and $s=9$.

The weather man observed $9$ days.